# IntelliJ IDEA load module error

Tags: intellij-idea, module

I am in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2.  I recently renamed a module from `mod_plus` to `exp-packs` and now I keep getting the error:
 `Error Loading Project: Cannot load module mod_plus`

The old module does not exist.  Under **File-> Project Structure->Modules->Dependencies** it does not show up, it *was* there, but I removed it when I first saw the error.  It does not show up in the .iml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="PYTHON_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$" />
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="module" module-name="Pyhton-Snippets" />
    <orderEntry type="module" module-name="exp_packs" />
  </component>
</module>
```

In the event log, when I click 'Details' and it asks do I want to remove, I click YES and it is gone for that session, but on restart it comes back. Any thoughts on how to get rid of it?

Comment: Check `.idea/modules.xml` file and fix the path there.

Comment: thanks man, that's where it was.  please add an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA loads modules according to `.idea/modules.xml` file which contains the relative paths to the `.iml` files.

If you rename a module in IntelliJ IDEA using refactoring, `modules.xml` file is updated automatically. In other cases you may need to update the path manually.

Comment: In my case, when I use the Command Line App project template, it consistently names the file, "untitled104.iml" which causes the behavior op mentioned; renaming to the actual file name addresses the issue.